# Fault/Technicalities with poynting theorem

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, charge, poynting-vector

When finding the force on a system of  point particles $Q_{1}, Q_{2}$, we need to use the formula

$$\vec{F} = Q_{1} \vec{E_{2}}$$

Where $\vec{E}_{2}$ is the field ONLY due to the charge $Q_{2}$, since the particles own field doesn't effect it.

The standard generalisation to a continuous  distribution is

$$\vec{F_{net}} = \iiint \rho \vec{E} dv,$$

where $\vec{E}$ is the field due to some external source. So we are effectively ignoring the force on the distribution due to its own $\vec{E}$ field and only focusing on the force due some externally applied field.

**Poynting theorem:**

However, let's look at poyntings theorem.  We start with

$$\vec{F_{net}} = \iiint \rho (\vec{E}+\vec{v} × \vec{B}) dv.$$

In poyntings theorem, $\vec{E}$ is usually interpreted as the whole field, instead of just one due to some external field.

Surely to give correct results, the field of the charge in question should technically be taken away from the resultant field in order to be correct, much like with the point charge case.

The resolution as I understand it, is that because we know the field from each element $\rho dv$ is effectively zero, the net outcome is the same.

However where is the mathematical proof that is identical for a finite $\rho$? If it was just a scalar addition of $\rho dv$, then the proof wouldn't be obvious? But because we are integrating, we know that the infinite additions of differentials would add up. (Although I can kind of see why it doesn't make a difference but I would like some rigour here)

This is ESPECIALLY important if we are using poyntings theorem with point charges. As poyntings theorem is a statement about the WHOLE field and not just parts of it, so point charges would break the statement at $r=0$ as $\vec{E}$ is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Poynting's theorem assumes that expressions such as $\mathbf j \cdot \mathbf E$ and $\int E^2 dV$ are meaningful.

When there is charge concentrated to a line or to a point, this is not the case in the points of space where the charge is. Hence the Poynting theorem is valid only in regions that do not have such singularities, and hence the theorem is of limited use/irrelevant for evaluating work-energy balance of such bodies.

The reason is that when charge is concentrated to a line or to a point, total electric field diverges in such lines/points, and cannot be used to find electric force and work of such force on that charge. Then, one way to define electric force on such singular charge is to use just external field, due to charges other than the charge that is subject to that force. In case of point charges, this then leads to a generalization of the original Coulomb law, where there are as many independent electric fields as there are point charges.